# One-row table with fixed height and flexible width

Tags: html, html-table, word-wrap

How to create the one-row table, that has fixed TR height (the limit is two rows), but each TD has flexible width and forced word-wrapping.

The main question: is it possible to force each TD to use always the complete height (use two rows) when there is more then one word, i. e. if TD contains one word it should be displayed in one row, if TD contains more then one word it should be displayed in two rows (in this case browser should set the TD width automatically).

Comment: Are you trying to do this automatically or can you run the data through PHP or something? As Jukka said, this isn't really possible. If you could build out the logic, you could probably use PHP to structure the table.

Comment: Yes. I can use back-end. I use ASP.NET MVC. "If you could build out the logic, you could probably use PHP to structure the table." - What do you mean?

Comment: Like if are pulling the data from a db you can look at the array, count the number of items, and construct a switch statement that recreates the table. If you aren't pulling from a db, but from a string, you can throw that into an array. My mentioning of PHP was only an example, you can do it in ASP.NET. Please don't ask how, I am a php guy not .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be impossible. The table layout mechanism tries to avoid line breaks inside cells when there is enough horizontal space. By setting e.g. `width: 0` on the cells, you could override this so that the browser makes each cell as narrow as possible (effectively, as wide as the widest word, in the case of pure text content), but then e.g. three words make three lines, causing the `height` setting to be overridden.

If you specify the context and purpose of wanting such a layout, perhaps a new, solvable problem can be formulated.